# handaling hebrew input in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a simple app that takes a list of movies in Hebrew and matches the user's input to the list.
if the input exists it will display the name of the movie and its id.

I have two problems one is that I'm unable to get input in Hebrew with an EditText.

the second problem is that the .equals() function creates an error:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

this is the code :

```java
    String str = MovQuery.getText().toString();
     for(int i=0;i<movies.size();i++) {
       if(movies.get(i).getName().equals(str) ==true){
         disp.setText("your movie is here");
       }
```

I don't know how to solve this problem and I would love some help

Answer (score 1):

Delete the == true, I don't think it has to do with the error but it's not how to write clean code.

```
String str = MovQuery.getText().toString();
 for(int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
   if(movies.get(i).getName().equals(str)){
     disp.setText("your movie is here");
   }
}
```

I think you forgot to assign the EditText to a widget. Use The findViewById method.

Rak Briout :)

Comment: the EditText is assigned to a widget so I think that's not the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's assigned to the right widget? (I can't even count how many times it happened to me). Also, check if the movie ArrayList and its values(such as name) are initialized.

Comment: I checked if coding Java with Hebrew is ok. it didn't make any problems so I guess it's just the ArrayList or the name value of it.

Comment: Yup that seems to be the problem my String seperation system was worng so it cused a null expectation. Toda raba